# Update log file with date line with bash

Tags: bash, mercurial, centos

I have a simple Mercurial update script that runs to pull the latest build to update a site. Right now I have it set to log itself but I cant get it to append its next entry at the end of the file with a date. I have some things I tried but they are not working how I would like it to.

update.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source /home3/nwrepai1/public_html/wonunder5/config.sh

echo "$TIMESTAMP Updated" >> $LOGFILE

hg pull -u -b default >> $$LOGFILE
```

config.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
LOGFILE="/home3/nwrepai1/public_html/wonunder5/update_log.txt"
TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the LOGFILE variable in the 'hg' line - two dollar signs. Remove one.